# Flipping variable length subvectors inside a numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vector, vectorization

I have a problem that requires me to re-order elements in subvectors within a long vector in a specific way such that the first element of the subvector remains in place, and the remaining elements are flipped.

For example:

`vector = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and the subvectors have length 3 and 5, then the flipped version would be:

`vector = [0, 2, 1, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4]`

A naive way of doing this would be:

```py
import numpy as np

vector = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] # the vector to flip
subVecStartIdxs = [0, 3] # start position of each subvector

    for jj in range(0, len(vector)-1):
        vector[subVecStartIdxs[jj]+1:subVecStartIdxs[jj+1]] =
        np.flipud(vector[subVecStartIdxs[jj]+1:subVecStartIdxs[jj+1]])
 #do the last one:
    faceIdx[fStartIdx[jj]+1:fStartIdx[jj+1]] =
    np.flipud(faceIdx[fStartIdx[jj]+1:fStartIdx[jj+1]])
```

Can you think of a faster way to do this? I cannot find a way to vectorise this... The speed is ok for small vectors, but million+ lengths it becomes very slow.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this in the end was to determine the unique lengths of the subvectors and create 2D arrays that are groups of these, where the 2D array is nSubVectors long, and has zeros at locations where the subvectors have different lengths to the current length.

From there, the entire 2D array can be flipped from left to right, excluding the first column, which I believe is O(1) in numpy.

Then, we just loop over each unique subvector length. In my case, this is very efficient because there are only ~10 of these, but there are millions of subvectors.

There is a bit of data management in rearranging this all to the original data structure, but it's really just some admin.

This results in a > 100x speedup from the naive loop presented in my original question.